# PHP SOAP Request with Header Authentication

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to use the code below to make a SOAP request to a vendor's web service:

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://my.domain.com/wsdl/GuestService.WSDL', array('connection_timeout' => 15, 'trace' => 1));
 $ns = 'http://vendor.domain.com/';

 $headerbody = array('brand' => 'BRAND1', 
                'locale' => 'en_us', 
                'securityCredentials'=>array('applicationId'=>'ABCDEF', 'token'=>'123456789123456789123456789')); 

 $header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'Header', $headerbody);        

 $client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 

 $result = $client->getGuest(array('guestID' => '000787'));
```

However, I'm getting an error back that no credentials were supplied so I must be doing something wrong.  Error message:   Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:NO_CREDENTIALS]

I reached out to the vendor and they sent me an XML sample of how they're expecting to receive the data:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prox="http://vendor.domain.com" xmlns:gues="http://vendor.domain.com/guest">
  <soapenv:Header>
  <prox:brand>BRAND1</prox:brand>
  <prox:locale>en_us</prox:locale>
  <prox:securityCredentials>
     <prox:applicationId>ABCDEF</prox:applicationId>
     <prox:token> 123456789123456789123456789</prox:token>
  </prox:securityCredentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <gues:getGuest>
     <guestID>000787</guestID>
  </gues:getGuest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I thought I had accounted for everything in the above but maybe I'm missing something obvious.  Really appreciate any help!

UPDATE:
I downloaded SoapUI so I could see what's going on.  It turns out the XML being generated is almost correct with one small issue....the header is inserting `<item>` and `<key>` tags within the XML:

```
<securityCredentials>
    <item>
        <key>applicationId</key>
        <value>ABCDEF</key>
    </item>
</securityCredentials>
```

What I need is:

```
<securityCredentials>
    <applicationId>ABCDEF</applicationId>
    <token>123456</token>
</securityCredentials>
```

If I could eliminate the tags, the XML would be correct.  I've researched and can't seem to find a specific flag or setting so still stuck on what to do next.

Comment: Can you get a copy of exactly what you sent to see where the XML differs from what they expect?

Comment: Hi!  I have requested it but I doubt I'll get it from them.  Is there any way you know of to view the XML on my server side?

Comment: You can use `echo $variableName;` or `var_dump($variableName);` to see the structure of your php variables.